# Compile Latex from Prolog

Tags: shell, prolog, latex

I wrote a Prolog predicate that generates a Latex file, and I am looking for a way to be able to compile such a file automatically, within Prolog, to return instead the associated PDF file. I have found the shell predicate (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=shell/2) but I can't figure out how to properly make it work.

In case it is of any relevance, I am using SWI-Prolog 7.1.33 in a Mac.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What command you use in a Bash shell (e.g. in Terminal.app) to compile and generate the PDF from the LaTeX file? What error you get if you use the same command as the first argument to the `shell/2` predicate?

Comment: I use "pdflatex file.tex". When I type

shell('pdflatex file.tex', E).

it returns E=127 (whose meaning I don't understand), and it generates neither the pdf file nor the log file.

Comment: Error 127, assuming a Bash shell, means "command not found". Likely the `pdflatex` command can not be found on the `PATH` for the shell started by the `shell/2` predicate. Try calling the `pdflatex` command using its full, absolute, path.

Answer (score -1):

The traditional predicate to execute shell commands is `system/1` that works in Unix-like and MS-Windows systems. For instance

```
?- system('echo a').
```

writes a `a` in a Unix-like system.

Comment: It depends on the Prolog system. B-Prolog and ECLiPSe do provide a `system/1` predicate. CxProlog uses a `os_run/1` predicate. Lean Prolog uses `system/4`. Quintus Prolog uses `unix/1`. Qu-Prolog uses `os/1`. But most systems nowadays provide a `shell/1-2` predicates.

Comment: @PauloMoura Thanks for the update: I was not sure whether `system/1`, that is also used in Yap, was available in SWI, and that is why I used *traditional* in my answer.

Comment: From my experience, `shell/1-2` is currently the most portable solution (when using POSIX systems; Windows is a bit more tricky as you may or may not get your command run on a `cmd` shell). But not a universal one. Also, as you point out, some systems do also provide a `system/1` predicate, likely for compatibility with old code.

Comment: It is strange there is no ISO predicate for this.

Comment: The ISO standard doesn't even specify a way to consult/compile Prolog text.